# finding counts assigned to another field's value

Tags: sql, oracle11g

```
Create table t1 (col1 (number), col2 (number), col3 (number);

Insert into t1 values (1,1,1);
Insert into t1 values (1,2,5);
Insert into t1 values (1,3,1);
Insert into t1 values (2,1,1);
Insert into t1 values (2,1,1);

Desired result
 col1  col2
  1     3
  2     2
```

I need to return the value in col1 and the count of values found in col 2 for each distinct col1 value.  Do not need col3

Comment: Can you show us some of your attempts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select col1, count(col1) from t1
group by col1
```

Comment: dang that is simple... I cannot believe it works... but it does..!!  Thank you!!